# Store two variables from two separate clicks in JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am currently making a JQuery chess game and on the surface things are working as expected. However I have noticed an error that could break everything later on.

There are two clicks that take place for a move to be made, first on the piece and then on the cell, the *id*, *class*, and *value* of the empty cell and piece must be stored. But because of the way `var`(can change like `let`) and `$(document).("click", function (event) {...})`  works only a single variable is stored for the *id*, *value*, and *class* of the cells, so only the latest click (the cell the piece must go) will be stored as a variable. This means that later one when the cells are being reset (so the new location of the piece is marked as *'piece'* and the old location as *'cell'*, and *id* + *class* is carried down) there will be only one variable that has been stored.

**Is there any way I can fix this?** I have also tried using `const` and `let` for the piece and the cell respectively but when these are used the code doesn't function at all.

Just to be clear this issue isn't causing errors now but could when updating the html. Not having different variables for cell and piece, could led to the first move working but as a cell is marked as a piece and vice visa the second, third, fourth, ect. will not.

Code:

```
$(document).on("click", function (event) {
                var x = event.pageX;
                var y = event.pageY;
                var clickedElement = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
                var value = $(clickedElement).attr('value');
                var id = $(clickedElement).attr('id');
                var color = $(clickedElement).attr('class');

                if (id !== undefined && selectedPiece === null && id.includes('piece')) { //selects piece
                    console.log('piece');
                    selectedPiece = id; 
                    enlargeBackground()
                }

                else if (id !== undefined && moveToSquare === null && id.includes('cell')) { // selects empty cell
                    console.log('blank');
                    moveToSquare = value;
                    console.log(value)
                    move();
                }
                    

})
// further down the document...

function update(id, class, color) {

 var updateId = document.getElementById(`${selectedPiece}`).innerHTML = `<td> class=${color} value=${value} id='cell'></td>` 
 var updateId2 = document.getElementById(`${moveToSquare}`).innerHTML = `<td class=${color} value=${value} id=${selectedPiece}></td>`
}
```

mrt

Comment: Your variables are declared inside your function. Which means when the function ends, they are gone. You cannot use `color` outside of the click handler.

Comment: Also note that you should change your entire approach to this. Your app state shouldn't live in your HTML. You should have an external data structure to store the state of the chessboard, i.e. which field contains which piece. Then you wait for a click by the user and if one occurs, update the state, then the visual representation (HTML).

Comment: `$(document).("click",` "*works as a loop*" - nope - it works as an *event*.   It only runs once when you actually click.   You're already doing the right thing with check for `selectedPiece === null`.  You can add a simple `console.log("test")` inside the click event to see when it fires (F12 in browser to see console).   It's unclear what you issue is.

Comment: @ChrisG the 'update' variables are inside a different function where color is declared, just forgot to add it! (just updated the question now) I will look into external data structures as well! Thank you.

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/ma0yxtfu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I decided to move my answer down here. After a bit of thinking I came to the now obvious conclusion of simply storing each variable as a const for each of the seperate clicks, thus they cannot be overridden.

```
$(document).on("click", function (event) {
                var x = event.pageX;
                var y = event.pageY;
                var clickedElement = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
                var value = $(clickedElement).attr('value');
                var id = $(clickedElement).attr('id');
                var color = $(clickedElement).attr('class');

                if (id !== undefined && selectedPiece === null && id.includes('piece')) { //selects piece
                    console.log('piece');
                    selectedPiece = id; 
                    enlargeBackground()
                    const pieceValue = value; //storing each variable as a const for the first click
                    const pieceId = id;
                    const pieceColor = color;
                }

                else if (id !== undefined && moveToSquare === null && id.includes('cell')) { // selects empty cell
                    console.log('blank');
                    moveToSquare = value;
                    console.log(value)
                    move();
                    const cellId = id; //storing each variable as a const for the second click
                    const cellValue = value;
                    const cellColor = color;
                }
//further down
function update(cellId, cellValue, cellColor, pieceId, pieceValue, pieceColor) {
      //code from before
      cellColor = null;
      cellValue = null;
      cellId = null;
      pieceId = null;
      pieceValue = null;
      pieceColor = null;
}
```